# How to separate nested table conspicuously?

Tags: html, css

How can i separate nested table in lower table as conspicuously as in upper table?

Upper table is not proper though.

I am trying to get Settlements  Finance Time 3  Time 5  Bad Good in a single line in lower table.

Here is my code:

```css
.my-table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.my-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ddd;
}

.my-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table class="my-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Service</th>
    <th>Provider</th>
    <th>Check</th>
    <th>Marker</th>
    <th>Captured Time</th>
    <th>Final Time</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sub Heading</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Custody C</td>
    <td>I</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Settlements</td>
          <td>Finance</td>
          <td>Time 3</td>
          <td>Time 5</td>
          <td>Bad</td>
          <td>Good</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Crossroad</td>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>Complete</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Partial</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>Time 4a</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Time 4b</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>Time 6a</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Time 6b</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td>Ok</td>
          <td>danke</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table class="my-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Service</th>
    <th>Provider</th>
    <th>Check</th>
    <th>Marker</th>
    <th>Captured Time</th>
    <th>Final Time</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Sub Heading</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Custody T</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Trades</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Position</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>Latest</td>
    <td>TIME 1</td>
    <td>TIME 2</td>
    <td>Good</td>
    <td>My Comments</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Custody C</td>
    <td>I</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Settlements</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Crossroad</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Finance</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>Complete</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Partial</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>


        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Time 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>Time 4a</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Time 4b</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Time 5
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>Time 6a</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Time 6b</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Bad</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ok</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Good</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>danke</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can style each table any way you want.

Comment: add `vertical-align: top` to the `td` containing the `table`..

Comment: You should not nest tables....use `colspan` and `rowspan` to get the desired affects. Also you might consider using CSS to position your elements instead of a table especially if you want to style parts of it differently.

Comment: @sorayadragon That does not give my answer but something better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question:

> I am trying to get Settlements Finance Time 3 Time 5 Bad Good in a single line in lower table.

Vertically aligning your table cells will bring the content to the top of the cells, regardless of how many lines of content follows.

```
.my-table td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

JSFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/y1Lr0mzw/

Please let me know if I missed what you were trying to accomplish.